# How to add a frame inside a JinternalFrame(like MDI FORMS)in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mdi

I am trying to code a swing program using menus and mdi forms to create a collection of swing applications in a single application like a tool.

I created some menus that should contain all swing applications!
So far it is good!

The problem is when i call the other program class(  corpustest2 call=new corpustest2();)

I can use the methods by calling the object!.I cannot fit into my menu action listener-internal frame!
it just showing in a separate frame!

this is the main part I am struggling!

I need to put the frame fit inside the internal frame and as mdi forms!

SO i can add all my swing applications inside one swing application so called as tool!
I am 3 months old to java!

Any suggestions&helps are welcomed
Below code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class corpustest4 {

    private JPanel pnlMain;
    private JDesktopPane desk;

    public corpustest4(){
        pnlMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()){
            @Override public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(600,600);
            }
        };
        desk = new JDesktopPane();

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Internal Frame");
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem();

        item.setAction(new AbstractAction("Create New") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JInternalFrame iFrame = new JInternalFrame("Created from Menu");
               iFrame.pack();
                iFrame.setResizable(true);
                iFrame.setClosable(true);
                iFrame.setIconifiable(true);
                iFrame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
                iFrame.setLocation(0, 0);
                iFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                iFrame.setVisible(true);
                corpustest2 call=new corpustest2();
                call.generate();
                desk.add(iFrame);
                //I tried to add call to desk but an argument cannot be added!
            }
        });
        menu.add(item);
        bar.add(menu);
        pnlMain.add(bar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pnlMain.add(desk, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private JPanel getUI(){
        return pnlMain;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new corpustest4().getUI());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the corpustest2 class program

```
public class corpustest2 implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame;
private JLabel lblSourceFolderfiles;
private JButton btnChoosedirectoryfrom;
//  private JLabel lblListFilesBelow;
private JButton btnDisplay;
private JTextField destPath;
private JTextField searchBox;
private JCheckBox chckbxSelectAll;
private JLabel lblNoOfFiles;
private JTextField noOfFileTxt;
private JButton btnGenerate;
private JLabel lblDestinationFolderTo;
private JButton btnBrowse;
private JPanel middlePanel;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;

//Objects
private List<Box> boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
private List<JCheckBox> checkBoxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
private Map<String, String> fileNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
//Variables
private int selectedCounter;

public corpustest2() { 
frame = new javax.swing.JFrame( "Search Box" );
frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1366, 700));
frame.pack();
//frame.getContentPane().setLayout( null );
frame.setSize( 1202, 692 );
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setExtendedState( frame.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


lblSourceFolderfiles = new JLabel("Source Folder/ Files");
lblSourceFolderfiles.setBounds(6, 17, 138, 14);
frame.getContentPane().add(lblSourceFolderfiles);

btnChoosedirectoryfrom = new JButton("ChooseDirectory From");
btnChoosedirectoryfrom.setBounds(141, 9, 170, 30);
btnChoosedirectoryfrom.addActionListener(this);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnChoosedirectoryfrom);

//  lblListFilesBelow = new JLabel("List files Below to choose ");
//lblListFilesBelow.setBounds(344, 17, 180, 14);
//frame.getContentPane().add(lblListFilesBelow);

btnDisplay = new JButton("Select To Display");
btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
btnDisplay.setBounds(534, 9, 180, 30);
btnDisplay.addActionListener( this );
// frame.getContentPane().add(btnDisplay);

searchBox = new JTextField();
searchBox.setBounds(79, 56, 772, 40);
searchBox.setFont( new Font( "Latha", Font.BOLD, 20 ) );
searchBox.setHorizontalAlignment( JTextField.CENTER );
searchBox.setEditable(false);

frame.getContentPane().add( searchBox );

middlePanel = new JPanel ();
 // middlePanel.setBorder ( new TitledBorder ( new EtchedBorder (), "Display Area" ) );
  middlePanel.setBounds(5, 100, 1300, 1200);
// middlePanel.setSize(1200, 700);
// middlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 600));


chckbxSelectAll = new JCheckBox("SELECT/DESELECT ALL");
chckbxSelectAll.setBounds(25, 557, 97, 23);
chckbxSelectAll.setFont( new Font( "Latha", Font.BOLD, 19 ) );
chckbxSelectAll.addActionListener(this);    
//  frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxSelectAll);

lblNoOfFiles = new JLabel("NO of Files Selected");
lblNoOfFiles.setBounds(79, 631, 139, 14);
frame.getContentPane().add(lblNoOfFiles);

noOfFileTxt = new JTextField();
noOfFileTxt.setBounds(243, 623, 86, 30);
frame.getContentPane().add(noOfFileTxt);
noOfFileTxt.setColumns(10);
noOfFileTxt.setEditable(false);

btnGenerate = new JButton("Generate");
btnGenerate.setBounds(411, 597, 160, 65);
btnGenerate.addActionListener(this);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnGenerate);

lblDestinationFolderTo = new JLabel("Destination PathTo Generate Files");
lblDestinationFolderTo.setBounds(553, 561, 226, 14);
 // frame.getContentPane().add(lblDestinationFolderTo);

btnBrowse = new JButton("Browse");
btnBrowse.setBounds(780, 561, 89, 23);
btnBrowse.addActionListener(this);
// frame.getContentPane().add(btnBrowse);

destPath = new JTextField();
destPath.setBounds( 553, 600, 400, 30 );
destPath.setFont( new Font( "Latha", Font.BOLD, 20 ) );
// frame.getContentPane().add( destPath );

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("ChooseDirectory From")) {
        chooseDirectoryFrom();

//  } else if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Select To Display")) {            
    //  selectToDisplay();
    } else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("SELECT/DESELECT ALL")) {
        selectAllMethod();
//  } else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Browse")) {
    //  outputDirSelection();
    } else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Generate")) {
        generate();
    }
}

public void chooseDirectoryFrom() {
    String tempStr = null;
     try {
               UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        Font font = new Font("Latha", Font.ITALIC, 10);
        fileChooser.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.PLAIN, 13));
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fileChooser.setFont(font);
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            tempStr = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();

        }
        if (tempStr != null && !tempStr.trim().equals("")) {
            searchBox.setText(tempStr);
            // Enable the search button
        //  btnDisplay.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //btnDisplay.setEnabled(false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//  public void selectToDisplay() {            //disabled btn to display
    File sourceFolder = null;
    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    Box.createGlue();
    if (boxList.size() != 0) {
        middlePanel.remove(scrollPane);
        middlePanel.repaint();

        frame.repaint();
        boxList = new ArrayList<Box>();
        checkBoxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
        fileNamesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        selectedCounter = 0;
        noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
    }

    sourceFolder = new File(searchBox.getText());
    File[] sourceFilesList = sourceFolder.listFiles();
    JCheckBox cb1 = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < sourceFilesList.length; i++) {
        if (sourceFilesList[i].isFile() & sourceFilesList[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            fileNamesMap.put(sourceFilesList[i].getAbsolutePath(), sourceFilesList[i].getName());
            cb1 = new JCheckBox(sourceFilesList[i].getAbsolutePath()); 
            cb1.setFont(new Font("Latha", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 15));
            box.add(cb1);
            checkBoxList.add(cb1);
            chckbxSelectAll.setSelected(!cb1.isSelected());
             box.add((chckbxSelectAll),0);

             cb1.setSelected(!cb1.isSelected());
             selectedCounter += 1;
             noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
             cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if (((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).isSelected()) {

                        selectedCounter += 1;

                    } else {
                        selectedCounter -= 1;
                        if (selectedCounter < 0) {
                            selectedCounter = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    boxList.add(box);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(box);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150, 470));
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy ( ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
//   middlePanel.add ( chckbxSelectAll );
    middlePanel.add ( scrollPane );
   frame.getContentPane().add(middlePanel);
   frame.repaint();
  frame.validate();
}

public void selectAllMethod() {
    Iterator<JCheckBox> i = checkBoxList.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {

    JCheckBox tmp = i.next();

        if (chckbxSelectAll.isSelected()) {
            tmp.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
            tmp.doClick();

        } else {
            tmp.setSelected(false);
            selectedCounter -= 1;
            if (selectedCounter < 0) {
                selectedCounter = 0;
            }
            noOfFileTxt.setText(Integer.toString(selectedCounter));
        }
    }
}
    public void generate() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        destPath.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

        Iterator<JCheckBox> i = checkBoxList.iterator();
        boolean once=false;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            JCheckBox chkBox = i.next();
                if(chkBox.isSelected()) {
                    String fileName =  chkBox.getText();
                    String destPathStr = destPath.getText();
            //      System.out.println("filepathname = " + fileName);
                if(destPathStr != null) {
                //  System.out.println("destPath: " + destPath.getText());
                    //System.out.println("fileName: " + fileNamesMap.get(fileName));

                    boolean success = corpustest3.exlCreator(fileName, destPath.getText(), fileNamesMap.get(fileName));
                    if(success&&!once)  {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Completed. Pls refer to the path " +  destPathStr + " for output files"); once=true;  
                    }  else if (once!=true) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Error Occured!!!");once=true;
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OOPS.You have to set the destination path!!!");
            }
            }
        }}  


}

public boolean checkFileDuplicate(String destPathStr, String fileNm) {
//  System.out.println("destPathStr:" + destPathStr);
    File f = new File(destPathStr);
    File[] destFilesList = f.listFiles();
    for(File f1:destFilesList) {
        if(f1.getName().equals(fileNm)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    f = null;
    destFilesList = null;
    return false;
}


    public static void main(String args[]) {
     new corpustest2();
}

}
```

This below is the required class for corpustest2 :

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class corpustest3 {
// final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
public Map<String, Integer> getWordCount(String fileName) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                String tmp = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
                if (wordMap.containsKey(tmp)) {
                    wordMap.put(tmp, wordMap.get(tmp) + 1);
                } else {
                    wordMap.put(tmp, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
    return wordMap;
}

public List<Entry<String, Integer>> sortByValue(Map<String, Integer> wordMap) {
    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> set = wordMap.entrySet();
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>(
            set);
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1,
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });
    return list;
}

final static String WORKSPACE = "d:/testfolder/";

private static void createOutputFolder(String outputFolderName) {
    File outputDirectory = new File(outputFolderName);

    if (!outputDirectory.exists()) {
        try {
            outputDirectory.mkdir();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


public static boolean exlCreator(String WORKSPACE, String ouputDirectory,
        String filnm) {
    String outputFolder = "output/";
    String fileName, fileNameWPathInput;
    int serialNumber = 1;
    ouputDirectory = ouputDirectory + "/" + outputFolder;
    createOutputFolder(ouputDirectory);
    if(!checkFileDuplicate(ouputDirectory, filnm)) {
        corpustest3 mdc = new corpustest3();
        File folder = new File(WORKSPACE);
        if (folder.isFile()) {
            // File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            // for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            // if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            // fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            fileName = WORKSPACE;
            // fileNameWPathInput = WORKSPACE + fileName;
            fileNameWPathInput = fileName;
            Map<String, Integer> wordMap = mdc.getWordCount(fileNameWPathInput);
            List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = mdc.sortByValue(wordMap);
            String fileNameWPathOutput = ouputDirectory + filnm + "output.xls";
            try {
                HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("ResultSheet");

                HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
                rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("Serial No.");
                rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("Word");
                rowhead.createCell(2).setCellValue("Count");

                for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) serialNumber);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(serialNumber);
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(entry.getKey());
                    row.createCell(2).setCellValue(entry.getValue());
                    serialNumber++;
                }
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                        fileNameWPathOutput);
                workbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
                serialNumber = 1;
                System.out.println(fileNameWPathOutput + " is created");
                return true;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
                return false;
            }
            // }

            // }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean checkFileDuplicate(String destPathStr, String fileNm) {
    File f = new File(destPathStr);
    File[] destFilesList = f.listFiles();


    for(File f1:destFilesList) {
        if(f1.getName().equals(fileNm)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    f = null;
    destFilesList = null;
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // 1. FilePath and File Name, 2. Output Directory, 3. FileName
    exlCreator(WORKSPACE, WORKSPACE, "test");
}

}
```

Comment: What does corpustest2 class do?can you share the related code?

Comment: that class is a swing gui application.Just few mins ill post it :)

Comment: There's nothing you can really do `selectedCounter` is using a `JFrame` of it's own and, which is just a bad design, instead, it should use a `JPanel` as it's base component (and maybe provide a "showFrame" convenience method) then you could add that panel to what ever container you wanted

Comment: There's also a whole bunch of other questionable stuff going, avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @S.B Did you check out the corpustest2 class??

Comment: Like MadProgrammer mentioned,there are lot of modifications that needs to be done,like you are creating a JFrame inside corpustest2 class which is actually not needed,and many other things.Not clear on what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: When you run the corpustest2  class!,It runs a Swing gui,I want to access the swing gui in my corpustest4 class that has the mdi and internal frames!

Comment: corupustest4 program- i have idea on adding several swing gui inside to fit   mdi forms so that I can access all my swing gui applications in form of menus from a single swing gui(corpustest4).

Comment: Check out these links:http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Swing/1600__Java_Swing_MDI.htm
http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060505/ .Check how the JDesktopPane and JInternalFrames are handled.Might help you simplify your code.